# NullPointerException when adding to ArrayList [long post]

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am working on creating a regex parser for a class project, and I've run into a problem I can't figure out how to fix. Whenever it encounters a parenthesized group, it is supposed to add a placeholder to the `groups` ArrayList where a group can then be captured from a String. The problem is that it throws a NullPointerException whenever it attempts to add to this ArrayList. Here is the `Segment` constructor, where this occurs:

```
public Segment(String value, boolean capture) throws ParseException {
    values = new ArrayList<>();
    parse(value);
    minimum = 1;
    maximum = 1;
    matchNot = false;
    captureGroup = capture;
    if (capture) {
        RegexGUI.input.groups.add(""); //error occurs on this line
    }
}
```

Note that `RegexGUI.input` refers to the relevant instance of `Regex`, which the constructor for is here:

```
public Regex(String value) throws ParseException {
    this.value = value;
    segments = new ArrayList<>();
    groups = new ArrayList<>();
    anchorStart = false;
    anchorEnd = false;
    tokenize(value, true, false);
}
```

As you can see, `groups` is clearly initialized in the constructor. Also, the `Segment` constructor is only called in the `tokenize()` method in the `Regex` class, and that method is only called by the `Regex` constructor, so there is no possible way I could see that the problem would simply be that `groups` has not been initialized.

The entire stacktrace is here:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at regexparser.Segment.<init>(Segment.java:39)
    at regexparser.Regex.tokenize(Regex.java:57)
    at regexparser.Regex.<init>(Regex.java:27)
    at regexparser.RegexGUI.actionPerformed(RegexGUI.java:80)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This is the line of code in `tokenize()` mentioned in the stacktrace:

```
segments.add(new Segment(value.substring(0, value.indexOf(")")+1), true));
```

This is the line of code in `actionPerformed()` mentioned in the stacktrace:

```
input = new Regex(regexInput.getText());
```

I don't know if this is necessary to post or not, but here are my instance and class variables for each class:

`Regex` class:

```
String value;
ArrayList<Segment> segments;
ArrayList<String> groups;
boolean anchorStart;
boolean anchorEnd;
```

`Segment` class:

```
ArrayList<String> values;
int minimum;
int maximum;
boolean matchNot;
boolean captureGroup;

final static String UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
final static String LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
final static String DIGITS = "0123456789";
final static String[] SETS = {UPPERCASE, LOWERCASE, DIGITS};
final static String WORD = UPPERCASE + LOWERCASE + DIGITS + "_";

final static String WHITESPACE = " \r\n\t\f";
```

`RegexGUI` class:

```
Container contentPane;
JPanel panel;
GridBagLayout gridbag;
GridBagConstraints c;
JLabel regexPrompt, stringPrompt, result;
JTextField regexInput;
JTextArea stringInput;
JButton test;
static Regex input;
boolean match;
```

I would appreciate any help you guys can give me. I've tried looking up what might be causing this exception, but the only answer I can find is that `groups` is not initialized. I've searched through my code to try to figure out any way that the `Segment` constructor may be called before `groups` is initialized, but I can't see any way that would be possible.

Comment: @3kings I've already read that post. I still couldn't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Then read it again :). You need to find out what is `null` and debug why.

Comment: "RegexGUI.input.groups.add(""); "  Where is RegexGui.input instantiated? if it is, where is its groups field instantiated?

Comment: @Tunaki: `groups` has been initialized; it shouldn't be null.

Comment: @FredK: As I mentioned, it is instantiated here: `input = new Regex(regexInput.getText());`. This line is in `RegexGUI`.

Comment: @BethanyLouise Debug and you will know for sure what is `null`.

Comment: Try with the debugger: place a checkpoint some line before the line where you get the NPE, then click "Dubug application" (or something similar, depending on which IDE you're using) and then proceed step by step looking for variable instantiations (with F5 or F6, again, it depends on the IDE the correct keymap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is a catch 22

This line:

`input = new Regex(regexInput.getText());`

Will create the Regex object, then assign it.

However, whilst creating the Regex instance you try to reference the Regex.input instance before its actually finished, so it hasnt yet actually been assigned and is in fact still null.

A reasonably quick fix would be to call the `tokenize` method after constructing the object. So remove the `tokenize` call from the constructor and then run something like:

```
input = new Regex(regexInput.getText());
input.tokenize(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Calling `tokenize()` outside of the constructor works just fine. The only problem now is that it's throwing a StackOverflowError instead, but that's coming from elsewhere in the code, so I'll see if I can troubleshoot that myself.

Comment: Glad to hear, happy debugging with the next error!

Comment: If tokenizing is an essential part of constructing the regex, prefer to leave it in the constructor! Instead, do not add the empty string to groups within the Segment ctor, but within tokenize (`if(...) this.groups.add("")`) @cowls Still you had a good eye for -- +1...